# SUM points from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table with files and their have their points/score. Iam trying to summarize those points and print it. I have a where clause for id files, but if I select random files it has same score as others like where clause isnt working.

$id is correct for each file.

This is my query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *,SUM(body) FROM soubory, users, hodnoti WHERE
soubory.id='".$id."' AND soubory.users_id = users.id");
```

hodnoti table

```
users_ID  soubory_id  body
  14        44         7 
  15        44         9
```

And now, if there is no record (in table hodnoti) for soubory_id = 45 the result is same as for 44 despite of where clause.

users table

```
id   nick
14   user1
15   user2
```

soubory table

```
id   nazev  users_id
44   file1  14
45   file2  14
```

That query should help me print this:

Who uploaded, nazev(title) of the file and then points. But if file2 has no record in table hodnoti, still has score of file1. Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and desired output from the given data?

Comment: The question does not make much sense without seeing the table structure, some sample data and a desired result. You're basically cross joining 3 tables with a condition on only one of them which probably will not give a useful result.

Comment: @frky How about just `$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(body) FROM hodnoti WHERE soubory_id='".$id."'");` ?

Comment: It will maybe works, but then I have to use two queries for output as above

Comment: So i did multiple queries, and now its working, slightly more code, but its working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT *, SUM(hodnoti.body) as sum FROM soubory 
    INNER JOIN users ON soubory.users_id = users.id
    INNER JOIN hodnoti ON soubory.id = hodnoti.soubory_id
    WHERE soubory.id='".$id."' ";
```

$result = mysql_query($sql);

This query works for me. When i set id=44 and get a result and when set id=45 and get all null value. i have attached two result image. I have just create table and insert your given data and run query on phpmyadmin sql tab query box. You can try this for check your query works or not.

[image]
[image]

Comment: after fetch this query iam trying to do this-- >    
      $body =  $row['SUM(body)'];

But get this error: Undefined index: SUM(body) same if i try SUM(hodnoti.body)

Comment: Here is full query and result accessing process $id = 44;

$sql = "SELECT *, SUM(hodnoti.body) as sum FROM soubory
    INNER JOIN users ON soubory.users_id = users.id
    INNER JOIN hodnoti ON soubory.id = hodnoti.soubory_id
    WHERE soubory.id=".$id;

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['sum'];
} if you want more field to access then first you print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); and see the resulted array and set your access key in the while loop.

Comment: Ok, this is working, but Can i write a query which can return, those points, who upload it, when, and title of file? I need datas from three tables.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN`.

```
$sql = "SELECT *, SUM(hodnoti.body) as sum FROM soubory 
        INNER JOIN users ON soubory.users_id = users.id
        INNER JOIN hodnoti ON soubory.id = hodnoti.soubory_id
        WHERE soubory.id='".$id."' ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

**SUGGESTION:** Above is a direct answer for your question. Avoid using mysql_* statements as they are deprecated now. Learn mysqli_* or PDO and start implementing that.

Comment: still wrong numbers, returns only first record of table hodnoti and there is no record for this id.

Comment: @parag you should not use mysql-* family functions as those are depricated and you should always encourage the best practise of escaping before concatanatio. The best option will be using prepared sql query

Comment: I know. Still a direct answer to the question. Still will add it as a suggestion. Thanks :)